# Bluetooth inquiry of devices with IAC (inquiry access code) set different than GIAC?

Tags: android, bluetooth, network-scan

Is it possible to specify the inquiry access code for remote devices during inquiry? By default the GIAC (general inquiry access code) is used, but my remote devices have dedicated inquiry access codes. I don't know the addresses of those devices, but they are discoverable. Is it possible to define DIAC code during scan?

Comment: Even if the remote device is scanning using the DIAC code, they are supposed to responded to GIAC inquiry.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is to set the LAP address, but with the Java API from Android you can't. Android uses BlueZ Bluetooth stack so you should use this API.

Here you have an [example](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html) setting the LAP address.